# Passing a ios_base flag as a function argument

Tags: c++, ios, fstream

I was trying to write a number of functions to *edit*, *delete* and *add* data into a database in **C++**. To accomplish these tasks I am working with *fstream* and *struct* objects.

For example, to edit the data of a particular individual in the database, I have the function below.

```
void editRecord(std::fstream& file, std::string& fileName, int recNum)
{
    PersonalInfo dataType;

    file.open(fileName.c_str(), ios::out | ios::binary); // not sure, if it's necessary
    file.seekp(recNum*sizeof(dataType), ios::beg);
    file.tellp();

    std::cout << "Enter employee's name : ";
    getline(std::cin, dataType.personalName);

    std::cout << "Enter employee's address : ";
    getline(std::cin, dataType.personalAddress);

    std::cout << "Enter city : ";
    getline(std::cin, dataType.cityName);

    std::cout << "Enter state : ";
    getline(std::cin, dataType.stateName);

    std::cout << "Enter state's zip code : ";
    getline(std::cin, dataType.zipCode);

    std::cout << "Enter telephone number : ";
    getline(std::cin, dataType.telNumber);

    std::cout << "Enter the current account balance : ";
    std::cin >> dataType.accountBalance;

    std::cout << "Enter the date of the last payment.\n";
    std::cout << "Day : ";
    std::cin >> dataType.dateLastPayment.dDay;

    std::cout << "Month : ";
    std::cin >> dataType.dateLastPayment.dMonth;

    std::cout << "Year : ";
    std::cin >> dataType.dateLastPayment.dYear;

   file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&dataType), sizeof(dataType));

   file.close(); /// not sure, if it's necessary
}
```

However, with this function the user always finds the position of the desired element, he or she wants to edit by counting from the beginning, as shown in the line below

`file.seekp(recNum*sizeof(dataType), ios::beg)`

As a first approach this line works fine, when the number of clients/employee in database is less. However, this is not always the case, what happens when there hundreds or thousands of of entity in the data base? It becomes a pain in the neck.

So I thought, it would be best to let the user specify the location from where they want to begin the count(shift). So, how do I go about doing that ? When the user wants to edit the data of the last customer/client/employee? Or any other and the user only knows that aforementioned record is **x** position from the current position?

So, I tried to modify the prototype of the previous function so as it becomes

`void editRecord(std::fstream& file, std::string& fileName, int recNum, std::ios_base pos)`

where `ios_base pos` is one of the following flags

- `ios::beg`
- `ios::end`
- `ios::cur`

And `file.seekp(recNum*sizeof(dataType), std::pos)`, this is the solution I could think of at the moment.

But, this new version seems not to work. What I got after executing the code is

**../fileProcessing.cpp|126|error: 'pos' is not a member of 'std::ios' {aka 'std::basic_ios'}|**

Is there a way to pass one of those flags as argument of a function? Or, what do I have to change in the code above in order to have the function work?

Comment: ios_base and ios::beg types do not match. The whole premise is flawed.

Comment: This is what I understood when I got the error message.

Comment: The use actual type of `ios::beg`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/seekdir